# JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

I have two tables, AccountData and Relations.
They have one to many relation, to one account can belong more relations.

I try to write a test for its repository to test the saving functionality and I get:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.ACC_DATA(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into ACC_DATA (ACC_CURRENCY, STATUS, CREATED_AT, CODE, ACC_NBR, OWNER_ID, EP_ID, SUBTYPE_ID, TYPE_ID, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-197]
```

I define the primary key as follows:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ACC_DATA")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ACC_DATA", sequenceName = "SEQ_ACC_DATA", allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;
```

Any idea?

Thank yoou in advance!

Comment: Do you have any unique indexes on this table? Have you already checked if for some reason the next sequence value on `SEQ_ACC_DATA` have a match on your table?

Comment: no, I do not have any, it is a H2 database

Answer (score 1):

Code seems to be correct.

Compare the value of the `SEQ_ACC_DATA` Sequence in the DB and the Max value for the `ID` column of the `ACC_DATA` table.

If the ID column has value greater than the sequence, you'll need to increment the value of the Sequence so that new inserts can take place through code.

Comment: I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and H2 as the database.

The application created its own database tables.

I have the following mappings:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Relations> relations;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACC_DATA_ID")
    private AccData accountData;